# Vietjet Flight reservation Family Name, Middle or given Name

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I am booking a flight on Vietjet online, I have come across their name requirement which is

> Family Name:
>
> Middle and Given Name:

I have always seen/used First name/Family Name so before Confirming my ticket I wanted to make sure what to put here.

Example, my name is John Doe, my first name is John and my Last/Family Name is Doe, so according to the above my family name would be Doe, what would be my Middle and given name? Should i put my name as Doe John?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t have a middle name you would put:

> Doe
>   John

Not all people have middle names so the airline would understand this.

Comment: This answer does not concern people who *do* have middle names...

Comment: @mcantsin Some people only have 1 name.  And for fun [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: LOL - read the title. without middle name there is no issue, as the distinction between family name and given name is quite logic...

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth I entered my name information spelled correctly but in the wrong order (my friends who independently booked with VietJet also made the exact same mistake) and the gate agent was able to make the change without any cost. It seems like it happens all the time for non-Vietnamese speakers

Answer (score 1):

reply from VietJet says:

> Dear Sir/Madam, the passenger should book the ticket in the same order as the passport. Normally, the family name will be filled first; the rest should follow the order of the passport.

As Vietnamese use reverse order (Family-name Middle-name Given-name), this can be quite confusing, as international travelers are asked to use Family-name, Given-Name Middle-name.